# Angular 4, Unexpected token: name (Subject) during ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, uglifyjs

I have a Angular 4 application.

I can successfully build the project with `ng build`

But, when I run `ng build --prod` the following error is thrown.

> ERROR in vendor.4008cf7dff2b98412878.bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (Subject)
>   [vendor.4008cf7dff2b98412878.bundle.js:19471,6]

When I did some research, I saw uglifyjs not working with es6 and I changed target to es5 in my tsconfig file.

But I keep getting this error.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Here is angular-cli version

[image: Angular CLI Version]

Here is my **tsconfig.json** file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my **angular-cli.json** file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css",
        "../node_modules/ladda/dist/ladda-themeless.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js",
        "../src/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/mask/jquery.mask.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.tr.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/jsTree/jstree.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/nestable/jquery.nestable.js",
        "../src/assets/js/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/inspinia.js",
        "../src/assets/js/custom.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I used this "[aspnet/signalr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr-client)" package. I unistalled package from my application and problem is solved.

Now, I can successfully building the project with `ng build --prod` command.

Answer (score 4):

Run `ng build --prod --sourcemaps` to identify the package causing the problem.

Then you need to find a workaround. That's the challenge...